# ruby 1.9 3 with passenger 3.0.12 - Tempfile causes 'No such file or directory' *.lock when trying to rmdir

Tags: ruby, passenger, ruby-1.9.3, temporary-files, rmdir

i think ruby 1.9.3 is unable to create tempfile in /tmp directory. Problem error message:

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error No such file or directory   /tmp/RackRewindableInput20121031-8340-1qko694.lock  
/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:346:in rmdir'  
/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:346:in rmdir'  
/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:338:in ensure in locking'  
/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:338:in locking'  
/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:144:in block in initialize'  
/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb:133:in create'  
/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:134:in initialize'  
/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/rewindabl‌​e_input.rb:86:in new'
```

Comment: Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  No such file or directory - /tmp/RackRewindableInput20121031-8340-1qko694.lock
    /lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:346:in `rmdir'
    /lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:346:in `rmdir'
    /lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:338:in `ensure in locking'
    /lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:338:in `locking'
    /lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:144:in `block in initialize'
   /lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb:133:in `create'
    /lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:134:in `initialize'
  /lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/rewindable_input.rb:86:in `new'

Comment: Please add some more detil, in particular: when does this happen?  When you start Passenger?  When you perform some action from the irb console?

Comment: irb runs fine. but when the same action is performed from passenger, i get error...

Answer (score 1):

Reporting the same error, it happens when i try to generate a pdf file using prince xml:

Works fine on Local machine, development and production running webrick, but passenger causes a crash.

Heres my backtrace (short version):

```
  Compiled print/print_core.css  (1ms)  (pid 14275)
  Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 236ms

  Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - /*** PATH DELETED ***/tmp/cache/assets/10948d89a043b6251405277a36d3e0e2.cache20130517-14275-1l2wvu7.lock):
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:346:in `rmdir'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:346:in `rmdir'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:338:in `ensure in locking'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:338:in `locking'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:144:in `block in initialize'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb:133:in `create'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:134:in `initialize'
    activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/core_ext/file/atomic.rb:19:in `new'
    activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/core_ext/file/atomic.rb:19:in `atomic_write'
    activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb:91:in `write_entry'
    activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:140:in `write_entry'
    activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/cache.rb:364:in `block in write'
    activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/cache.rb:520:in `instrument'
    activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/cache.rb:362:in `write'
    sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:90:in `cache_set'
    sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:53:in `cache_set_hash'
    sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:24:in `cache_asset'
    sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
    sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
    sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
    sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
    sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `new'
    sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `build_asset'
    sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
    sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
    sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
    sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
    sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
    /var/www/*** PATH DELETED ***_core/lib/princely/pdf_helper.rb:83:in `asset_file_path'
    /var/www/*** PATH DELETED ***_core/lib/princely/pdf_helper.rb:29:in `block in make_pdf'
    /var/www/*** PATH DELETED ***_core/lib/princely/pdf_helper.rb:29:in `collect'
    /var/www/*** PATH DELETED ***_core/lib/princely/pdf_helper.rb:29:in `make_pdf'
    /var/www/*** PATH DELETED ***_core/lib/custom_pdf_helper.rb:28:in `make_pdf_with_defaults'
    /var/www/*** PATH DELETED ***_core/lib/custom_pdf_helper.rb:59:in `make_tmp_pdf'
    /var/www/*** PATH DELETED ***_concept/app/controllers/pdf_builder_controller.rb:171:in `build_pdf'
```

Problem is caused by permission problems when passenger is running as user 'nobody' which happens when config files owned by root.

Setting the following in your apache/passenger conf makes it work

```
PassengerDefaultUser www-data # should be same as apache user
```

Setting all the files/folders which are used by apache/rails app to

```
chown www-data:www-data
```

(In my case it was *chown -R tmp/*) makes it work.

**NOTE:** I think, actually the error is happening when ruby tries to actually write the tempfile, but obviously in this moment no error is trown. in the next step, ruby tries to delete a non-existing tempfile and crashed.

Hope it helped!